Reconnecting to a Powershell session
Let's suppose to start a process in a remote Powershell command prompt. This process prints output to the console:
PS local> $Session = New-PSSession -Credential $cred -ComputerName 192.168.0.135
PS local> Enter-PSSession $Session
[192.168.0.135]: PS remote> custom-process.exe
log1
log2
...

Then I close the powershell window.
Now I reopen a powershell window and reenter the remote session, then
PS local> $Session = New-PSSession -Credential $cred -ComputerName 192.168.0.135
PS local> Enter-PSSession $Session
[192.168.0.135]: PS remote>

I would expect to see all the logs that custom_process emitted, instead nothing. The proess is still running of course
[192.168.0.135]: PS remote> Get-Process

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
     67       5      880       4428       0.02   2860   0 ***
   1490      92    94520     131600       4.02   6336   0 custom-process


What should I do to reconnect to the exact same session used to start custom-process and see the logs that the process emitted to the console?

You would want to use Disconnect-PSSession and Connect-PSSession  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/connect-pssession?view=powershell-7.4

@CrookedJ I did, no difference. When I connect to the session and enter in it, it still doesn't show the logs
